# How do you make a batch file appear when you click on a file?

Tags: file, batch-file, password-protection, prompt

Is there a way to execute a batch file when you right or left click a file? I want to make a password batch file that will prompt the user for a password in order to open or edit that specific file. If the person gets it wrong then he can't edit nor open the file.

Comment: If you did use a batch file and wanted to make it more safe, you could use a program such as this one http://tinyurl.com/BatchToEXE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a round about way, yes. This script will create a private folder for you to store documents in and will prompt for a password before allowing access to it.

```
cls
@ECHO OFF
title Folder Private
if EXIST "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}" goto UNLOCK
if NOT EXIST Private goto MDLOCKER
:CONFIRM
echo Are you sure you want to lock the folder(Y/N)
set/p "cho=>"
if %cho%==Y goto LOCK
if %cho%==y goto LOCK
if %cho%==n goto END
if %cho%==N goto END
echo Invalid choice.
goto CONFIRM
:LOCK
ren Private "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}"
attrib +h +s "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}"
echo Folder locked
goto End
:UNLOCK
echo Enter password to unlock folder
set/p "pass=>"
if NOT %pass%== PASSWORD_GOES_HERE goto FAIL
attrib -h -s "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}"
ren "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}" Private
echo Folder Unlocked successfully
goto End
:FAIL
echo Invalid password
goto end
:MDLOCKER
md Private
echo Private created successfully
goto End
:End
```

See [this link](http://www.simplehelp.net/2010/11/29/how-to-create-a-password-protected-folder-in-windows-7/) and [this link](https://social.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/softwareresources/thread/9a0f17af-928e-4732-a3ba-90d54ed961ea) for more info.

Comment: Excuse me. How this Batch file can be executed when the user double-click on a file? (that is the topic of this question).

Answer (score 1):

Why not use real encryption like GPG? It's like, actual security man.

Your idea, even if it were possible (and I don't believe it be) is trivially defeatable, just open the file directly in whatever app it opens with.

Actually, it's *worse* than that, your suggestion would REVEAL the password, because it would have to be in the bat file somewhere.

Comment: I know that there is a way to secure a file with winwar and such but how do they do that? what makes them different then trying to do it yourself?